# Why is there no index for the returned template in the controller of the newly created Springboot project in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I created a new Spring Boot project in IntelliJ IDEA. Normally, we use the `@GetMapping` annotation in the controller to return a template, usually using `return "XXXX";` in my previous project, `"XXXX"` will be marked with an underscore, and Do not include underscores in new items.
Return value without underscore, Previous normal project:

[image]

No index in new project：

[image: No index in new project]

A similar problem also occurs. When using model to transfer data to the template engine in the controller method, and using `${}` in the Thymeleaf page, IntelliJ IDEA will not prompt the object that has been transferred in, and it needs to be entered manually, which causes great inconvenience. I'm a beginner.

Comment: Please share code snippets to better understand your problem

Comment: Please raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and attach a minimal reproducible project sample if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add Spring Boot facet to your project.

[image]

this is my specific version of IntelliJ IDEA

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using this version too, but it didn't solve my problem.